# Query multiple external data in parallel with bulk

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

We received documents (d1, d2, d3) from two different companies (c1, c2).
Each document has a property defining the company it belongs to.
Each company provides a REST service (s1, s2) to manage documents permissions.

Now, a user (u1) wants to load all his documents, which can be from different companies (query):

```json
{
  "user": "u1",
  "documents": [
    { "id": "d1", "company": "c1" },
    { "id": "d2", "company": "c2" },
    { "id": "d3", "company": "c1" },
  ]
}
```

Now, we need the OPA policies, which decides, whether to call s1 or s2 depending on the `company` field.
The answers from s1 when queried with d1 and d3 looks like this:

```json
[
  { "id": "d1", "read": true },
  { "id": "d3", "read": false }
]
```

The answer from s2 when queried with d2 like this:

```json
[
  { "id": "d2", "read": true }
]
```

The final OPA output should look like this (decision):

```json
[
  { "id": "d1", "read": true },
  { "id": "d2", "read": true },
  { "id": "d3", "read": false }
]
```

And here the questions (I'm new to Rego):

1. How would the Rego rules (policies) look like?
2. Is it possible to bulk the request with d1 and d3 for s1 or will it `http.send` once for each document?
3. Is it possible to do the call to s1 and s2 in parallel for better performance?